# Why "would rather" +noun is feasible?Without principal verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, adverb-position, would

A sentence from TE,however find no grammatical rules supporting the sentence.
Thanks you in advance.

**Many politicians, business people, intellectuals, journalists and even whisky-swilling
generals would far rather a more secular Pakistan.**

Comment: It may occur in some literature, but it's not standard. It normally takes a bare infinitival ("I would rather play golf) or a finite clause complement ("I would rather he played golf"). "Would rather" is an idiom in which it's just "would" that is an auxiliary verb

Comment: Sounds contextual correct in the passage.Generally speaking, editor from TE here is probably making some assumption or presumption of the development in Pakistan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Would rather” means “prefer” so:

......would rather (prefer) a more secular Pakistan (than)...

> “*I had enough of entertaining children and **Ann would rather a house full of cats**, dogs, with horses in the field*”. From [If It Wasn't for Bad Luck](https://books.google.it/books?id=CyiZUQoKsGgC&pg=PA7&dq=%22would%20rather%20a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCtqHyqvnfAhUQ16QKHQJ_D9c4ChDoAQhHMAY#v=onepage&q=%22would%20rather%20a%22&f=false)
>   By Alan Crowe.

Comment: Ah~Then the sentence makes sense.Much appreciate!

Comment: I'd say it means "Would prefer".